# SQLAlchemy - Getting Error with Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

So I'm using SQL Alchemy in my project, and I've reached the point where I'm starting to put certain components in their own threads.

To give some background, and in case I'm doing it the wrong way, I've created a function somewhere called `create_session` and it looks like this:

```
def create_session():
    engine = create_engine(con_str)
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    return Session()
```

And then in the constructor of each thread I just call:

```
self.session = create_session()
```

Now the code that's giving me trouble is this:

```
for f in os.listdir(self.input_dir):
    tasks.append(Task(job_id=self.id, file_name=f, task_id=f[f.rfind('_')+1:]))
    #-1 means the last element
    session.add(tasks[-1])
session.commit()

for task in tasks:
    task.submit()
```

This code is in a member function called `submit` of a SQLAlchemy Base model. It gets called by another thread. The `session` variable is created at the top of the script with:

```
session = create_session()
```

When the code runs like this, I get the MySQL error:

```
InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1205, u'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction') [SQL: u'INSERT INTO task (task_id, job_id, file_name, status, started, finished) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ('21', 'c182b73b-9ccc-430e-9317-05816e7494a7', 'hgbig_21', 'created', datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 29, 15, 58, 14, 992144), None)]
```

And when I issue `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` on the database, I don't see any other connections or processes locking the `task` table other than the one trying to issue this command.

What's interesting is that when I change the code to the following, and commit each time I add, the error goes away:

```
for f in os.listdir(self.input_dir):
    t=Task(job_id=self.id, file_name=f, task_id=f[f.rfind('_')+1:])
    #-1 means the last element
    session.add(t)
    session.commit()
    tasks.add(t)

for task in tasks:
    task.submit()
```

And also, before this code is run, there is nothing else that interacts with the `task` table. Not as much as a select query.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or explain to me what's going on here? Note that this is my first time using multi threading with SQLAlchemy.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution. I am running into a very similar problem.